# What "cloud storage " means in snowflake database storage layer?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am just confuse with the explanation given on multiple forum for database storage for snowflake. When they say that data is stored in the form of columner and optimised files in cloud storage, does it mean S3 bucket or azure blob storage? Does Snowflake store data or uses cloud host storage ?

Answer (score 1):

According to the paper [The Snowflake Elastic Data Warehouse](https://www.snowflake.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Snowflake_SIGMOD.pdf) (2016) - see paragraph **3.1 Data Storage**:

> Snowflake initially chose Amazon S3 to store table data, query
> results, and temp data generated by query operators (e.g. massive
> joins) once local disk space is exhausted, as well as for large query
> results. Metadata such as catalog objects, which table consists of
> which S3 files, statistics, locks, transaction logs, etc. is stored in
> a scalable, transactional key-value store, which is part of the Cloud
> Services layer.

Since then, and as of today, Snowflake has been made available to run also on [Azure](https://resources.snowflake.com/snowflake/providing-customer-choice-snowflake-on-azure?_ga=2.257054531.937186439.1616579504-1586048673.1604500790) and [Google Cloud](https://www.snowflake.com/news/snowflake-announces-general-availability-on-google-cloud/).

Therefore, when setting up a Snowflake account, the user is presented with the option of a cloud storage provider to use: for AWS Snowflake will use Simple Storage Service (S3), for Azure it will use Azure Blob Storage, and for Google Cloud it will use Google Cloud Storage (GCS).

Comment: In case it isn't clear from this answer: If you have set up your Snowflake instance on AWS then Snowflake will use S3 as the data storage layer, Azure -> Azure Blob, and if you're on GCP they'll use GCS.

Comment: @SimonDarr I'll make it clearer in my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The database storage is in files in S3, Azure Blob on Azure and GCP buckets (or whatever they're called). Data and storage are completely separate, unlike server based RDBMS such as REDSHIFT, where the servers have both compute and storage. See the Snowflake documentation for more detail.